# How can I apply grid-template-column to children inside an element

Tags: html, css

I have a grid parent that has rows. Rows has two children. The first child's width is unknown. I want to set auto column width. I can achieve this with this:

```css
.list {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
    gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <span>First Child</span>
  <span>Second Child</span>

  <span>First</span>
  <span>Second Child</span>

  <span>Long Text Child</span>
  <span>Second Child</span>
</div>
```

But I need a container element for the rows and I couldn't achieve the result as above:

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="row">
    <span>First Child</span>
    <span>Second Child</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <span>First</span>
    <span>Second Child</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <span>Long Text Child</span>
    <span>Second Child</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [subgrid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid) can be used to make the size of `.row` column tracks the same as of the parent grid.

The row should `span` all columns defined in the parent.

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="row">
    <span>First Child</span>
    <span>Second Child</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <span>First</span>
    <span>Second Child</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <span>Long Text Child</span>
    <span>Second Child</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "open" the rows with `display: contents` like so.

One downside, it treats the row wrappers as though they were not there so if you wanted additional styling for the rows that might be problematical.

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.row {
  display: contents;
}

span {
  outline: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="row">
    <span>First Child</span>
    <span>Second Child</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <span>First</span>
    <span>Second Child</span>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <span>Long Text Child</span>
    <span>Second Child</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: As you said I cannot apply additional styles for the rows. Thank you for your answer!